# cshtml - conditioning class by data-bind value

Tags: c#, html, razor

I want to show a textfield with   "eight columns" class if a data-bind is not null, and "sixteen columns" class if it is.

Something like:

```
if (data-bind: "value: myData" have value)

      <div class="eight columns">
else
      <div class="sixteen columns">
```

Is that possible directly on cshtml?

Comment: Does `myData` represent the condition you look at?

Comment: Yes, it does. Mydata contains (or not) text that may to be show into the textfield

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary operator directly into your attribute value like below:

```
<div class='@(myData != null ? "eight columns" : "sixteen columns")'>
```

Comment: thanks. But mydata not exist in the current context.  I can read it as  data-bind="value:myData"

Comment: @doxsi It is unclear what you're asking. If you want to set class attribute based on `myData` variable so that is what to do in Razor (cshtml) like I do in my answer.